# What font is used in the John Crerar Library?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, interface-design, signage, wayfinding

I visited [the John Crerar Library](https://www.lib.uchicago.edu/crerar/) at UChicago, and the font used in its interior looks fantastic to me.

[image]

I tried searching on [WhatTheFont](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/), and it told me the font is [BB Manual Mono™ (Pro)](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/boldstudio/bb-manual-mono-pro), but I don't think the result is accurate because the shape of the ampersand sign differs quite a bit.

Here are some additional samples you can check out.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: There are various differences between the BB Manual fonts and this one, though they are very similar: uppercase A has a wider bowl here, lowercase a has a curl at the end, etc.

Comment: Is it possible that this is a custom font?

Comment: Dont dorget to accept your answer once you can do so

Answer (score 4):

I sent an inquiry to an art studio on campus, and here is the reply I received

> The font you are referring to is called ERC. It is a proprietary typeface designed originally for the signage in the William Eckhardt Research Center (ERC). We did not design it. It was designed by our friends at Studio/lab, a Chicago design studio who also did the signage for Crerar.

See [here](https://studiolab.com/uchicago-erc) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. A lot of characters are very distinctive but I'm not finding it. If you want something similar with a monospaced/avant garde aesthetic, try Euclid Mono from Swiss Typefaces, BC Sklonar from Briefcase Type, Decima Mono by TipografiaRamis or AF Module Classic.